# Avoiding unenecessary table scans

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Col 1,
col 2,
.....
.....
from 
table1,
table2
........
........
where
join conditions1
join conditions1
................
.................
and
table1.day_key >= (select key from date_dim where value='01-JAN-2011')
and table1.day_key <= (select key from date_dim where value='31-DEC-2011')
and 
table2.day_key >= (select key from date_dim where value='01-JAN-2011')
and table2.day_key <= (select key from date_dim where value='31-DEC-2011')
```

Here I can see date_dim table is doing scan four in where condition, how to avoid it. date_dim table is not selected in main from clause. I dont have enviornment to test this unfortunatly. Database is oracle 10g

Comment: Interesting question, though I don't see any performance problem scanning that dimension table twice.

Comment: Yes, double as necessary. I wrote an answer with a sql solution for your problem. The table will be scanned only once per value, but you would be in the need to control the execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said I don't see a performance problem scanning that table double times as necessary.

A pure rewrite of query would be:

```
select 
  Col 1,
  col 2,
from 
  table1,
  table2,
  date_dim date_dim_start,
  date_dim date_dim_end
where
  join conditions1
  join conditions1 and
  table1.day_key >=  date_dim_start.key and
  table1.day_key <= date_dim_end.key and
  table2.day_key >= date_dim_start.key and
  table2.day_key <= date_dim_end.key and
  date_dim_start.value = '01-JAN-2011' and
  date_dim_end.value='31-DEC-2011';
```

But you should test it, in order to not suffer a performance hit.

Comment: I will test and it looks better as well instead of writing 4 sql queries.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is adding an index on `date_dim(value)`.  Before you do so, check the number of rows in the table.  If there's less than a 100, a table scan is not at all a bad thing.

You can avoid including the same subquery twice by moving it to a `cross join`, like:

```
from   ...
cross join
       (
       select  key 
       from    date_dim 
       where   value='01-JAN-2011'
       ) as dt1
....
where  table1.day_key >= dt1.key
```

Comment: my question is in query we are selecting 2 values and for that 4 times selecting a table, is there any way to avoid it? one option is with clause. anything apart from that?

Answer (score 1):

use can use with clause to get the value of key from date_dim and join the same in where clause.
this will speed up your query fetching cause while using with clause the values are stored in temp space.